# In Java the query does not work but in MySQL it works fine, how can I fixed this?

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have a strange problem with joining 2 tables. In java the query does not work, it prints only one row with repetition but in MySQL query it works fine. I need this data to write in a json file. How can I fix this problem? Please help. Note: For the table look up see the link: [Need to join 2 tables but except some rows in another table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278784/need-to-join-2-tables-but-except-some-rows-in-another-table-in-mysql)

Here is my code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

 public class ShowData {
      public void Display(){
         try{
             DBConnect2 dc = new DBConnect2();
             PreparedStatement ps = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
             Statement st= null;
             BufferedWriter wr1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("E:/workspace/Test/input/display.json")));
             String query5 = "SELECT DISTINCT k.source, k.target, k.frequency FROM links k "
                  + "LEFT JOIN logs g ON g.id = k.id "
                  + "WHERE  IFNULL(status, '') != 'Delete Edge' "
                  + "AND 'Bush' IN( k.source, k.target )";

             ps = dc.getCon().prepareStatement(query5);
             rs = ps.executeQuery();
             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
             JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
             JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
             while(rs.next()){
                   obj1.put("source", rs.getString("source"));
                   obj1.put("target", rs.getString("target"));
                   obj1.put("frequency", rs.getInt("frequency"));
                   list.add(obj1);
             }
             obj.put("links", list);
             wr1.write(obj.toString() + "\n");
             wr1.flush();
             System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public static void main(final String[] args){
          ShowData sw = new ShowData();
          sw.Display();
     }
}
```

Comment: `JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();` should go inside the `while` loop.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826029/what-simple-db-solution-do-i-use-to-extract-my-parsed-variables-from-eclipse-to/24826365#24826365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be right here

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
while(rs.next()){
    obj1.put("source", rs.getString("source"));
    obj1.put("target", rs.getString("target"));
    obj1.put("frequency", rs.getInt("frequency"));
    list.add(obj1);
}
```

You're creating `obj1` once and writing the content of each row to it. `JSONObject` acts like a map and if you write new data to an existing key, the new data will overwrite the old data. So your loop will overwrite the old data over and over again, till the last row is reached. Therefore only the content of the last row will be available after this loop.

To fix it, move `obj1` into the loop:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
while(rs.next()) {
    final JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    obj1.put("source", rs.getString("source"));
    obj1.put("target", rs.getString("target"));
    obj1.put("frequency", rs.getInt("frequency"));
    list.add(obj1);
}
```

Now you're creating a new instance of `JSONObject` in each iteration, store the data of the current row to it and add this instance to the `JSONArray`.